# MYSQL Group By Date Order By Book

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to list the best renting books from my database for every month of the year. I am trying to list a max of 10 books and list them from the most rentals downwards e.g.

- December | book name | 3 copies
- December | book name | 2 copies
- December | book name | 1 copies
- November | book name | 2 copies
- November | book name | 1 copies
- October | book name | 2 copies

Currently it is outputting randomly but grouping by the month. I will attach my schema and also my query.

**Query**

```
        USE data_mart;
        SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Rental Count', month(rental_date) as 'Month'
        FROM fact_rental
        GROUP BY month(rental_date), bookId
        ORDER BY month(rental_date) DESC;
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE fact_rental (
  rental_id INT(8) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cardNo int(11) NOT NULL,
  borrower_fname varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  borrower_lname varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  staffNo int(11) NOT NULL,
  staff_fname varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  staff_lname varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  branchId int(11) NOT NULL,
  branchName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  bookId int(11) NOT NULL,
  book_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  rental_date DATETIME,
  return_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  count_returns INTEGER(10) DEFAULT 1,
  count_rentals INTEGER(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1,
  FOREIGN KEY (staffNo) REFERENCES dim_staff(staffNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (branchId) REFERENCES dim_library_branch(branchId),
  FOREIGN KEY (cardNo) REFERENCES dim_borrower(cardNo),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookId) REFERENCES dim_book(bookId),
  PRIMARY KEY (rental_id) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS RentalCount, month(rental_date) as Month
FROM fact_rental
GROUP BY month(rental_date), bookId
ORDER BY RentalCount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: This will limit everything by 10 so it will only show 10 books, I want it to show 10 books for every month of the year.

Comment: @CurtisBoylan . . . Your problem statement is:  "I am trying to list a max of 10 books and list them from the most rentals downwards".  If you have a different question, I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Three people have already tried to help you with this one, and changing it would likely invalidate their answers.

Answer (score 0):

for the first 10 you can use limit 10

```
    USE data_mart;
    SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Rental Count', month(rental_date) as 'Month'
    FROM fact_rental
    GROUP BY month(rental_date), bookId
    ORDER BY month(rental_date) DESC limit 10;
```

but do the fact that months are recursive ..  you should check (or filter ) also for year eg:

```
    USE data_mart;
    SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS 'Rental Count', month(rental_date) as 'Month'
    FROM fact_rental
    GROUP BY month(rental_date), bookId
    where year(rental_date) = 2017
    ORDER BY month(rental_date) DESC limit 10;
```

Comment: This will limit everything by 10 so it will only show 10 books, I want it to show 10 books for every month of the year.

Comment: then you can't use a single query but a loop for each month with the query for the most rented  books

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way, but it could melt your database server down if the dataset is huge. This one is far from ideal, but with a 12-pieces `UNION` you could get the desired results (I've added a year for filtering by month):

```
(SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS rental_count, DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%M') as rental_month FROM fact_rental WHERE date_format(rental_date, '%Y-%m') = '2017-10' GROUP BY bookId ORDER BY rental_count DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT bookId, book_name, COUNT(*) AS rental_count, DATE_FORMAT(rental_date, '%M') as rental_month FROM fact_rental WHERE date_format(rental_date, '%Y-%m') = '2017-09' GROUP BY bookId ORDER BY rental_count DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION ALL
(...)
```